# Explicit inner class within Groovy script - is this possible?

Tags: groovy

experienced hand at Java, new to Groovy

Trying to create a Groovy **SCRIPT** with an inner class and not having much luck. One wrinkle is this code exists and executes within a 3rd-party app.

Here is a stone-simple **SCRIPT** that compiles/saves OK inside the 3rd-party app but does not seem to execute when I call it - nothing prints:

```
import java.io.*;

static class Inner {

    private Long   empId;
    private String empIName;

    // constructors
    public Inner() {}

    public Long getEmplId() {
        return this.emplId;
    }
    public void setEmplId( Long empId) {
        this.emplId = emplId;
    }
    public String getEmplName() {
        return this.emplName;
    }
    public void setEmplName( String empName) {
        this.emplName = emplName;
    }
}

// implicit main outside any enclosing braces
println("hello from implicit")
```

or less-optimal explicit class with explicit main()

```
public class Outer {

    static class Inner {

        private Long   empId;
        private String empIName;

        // constructors
        public Inner() {}

        public Long getEmplId() {
            return this.emplId;
        }
        public void setEmplId( Long empId) {
            this.emplId = emplId;
        }
        public String getEmplName() {
            return this.emplName;
        }
        public void setEmplName( String empName) {
            this.emplName = emplName;
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args) {
        println("hello there")
    }
}
```

which also does not seem to execute when I call it - nothing prints

So there's something blindingly obvious or fiendishly subtle about
why neither of these work within the 3r-party app. I don't have a way to test them outside the 3rd-party app.

TIA,

Still-Learning Steve

```
    }
```

Comment: why do you need your class to be `static`? without it it executes just fine